# Optimality Conditions of $ l_{\infty}$ minimization problem

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming, numerical-optimization

I have two questions. Firstly, i would like to find the optimality conditions of the following minimization problem:

$ \min \rvert Ax - b \rvert_{\infty}$

Secondly, how would the initial working set look like if I wanted to solve this problem with active set algorithm ?

Comment: For optimality, have you tried recasting it as a linear program and then taking the KKT conditions? This is the first approach that comes to mind.

Comment: Active set methods are used to solve optimization problems with constraints. The problem here is unconstrained, so an active set method would not apply.

Comment: @DavidM. when this problem is converted to a linear problem then we have inequality constraints?

Comment: In that case, yes. However, it would be _highly_ unusual to solve a linear problem (an LP) with an active set method. Is there a reason you want to do that?